React Native Access/Refresh Token Storage
We have been storing our access token and refresh tokens in keychain, but there has been some errors with saving and getting the keychain which affected my user experience. This cause quite a few undesirable features. These errors were also on the library level, so I can't really fix it myself. Is it safe to store the token pair in redux store instead?

why you not store in local storage, for example you can use react-native-mmkv for local storage.
